# upper bound of $\sum_{k=1}^n k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{k=1}^n k$

We know that

$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Now how do I show that it is not bounded?

Comment: I think you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n k$. The expression $\sum_{n=1}^n n$ is meaningless.

Comment: corrected, thanks

Comment: You still need to change $n=1$ to $k=1$.

Comment: @runway44 both expressions are equally meaningful.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For showing unboundedness is the same as showing the expression is greater than any any natural number for sufficiently big $n$

Let $a_n \ = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$

clearly $ a_n > n^2/2$

so for all $n>\sqrt{2M} \\a_n > M$

and as the set of naturals is unbounded we can always find such $n$ so we are done

Comment: oh! I see it is because of the Archimedean property

Comment: yes you are rright